# PostgreSQL pgAdmin не соединяется с сервером

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Впервые ставлю PostgreSQL. Установка прошла без ошибок. pgAdmin не может соединиться с сервером, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: pg_hba.conf настраивали?

Comment: нет, какие параметры там нужно менять?

Comment: Вам доступ только на localhost нужен, или база на удаленном сервере?

Comment: только на localhost

Comment: pgadmin application server - это не про postgresql. А про pgadmin 4. К базе на данном этапе не имеет отношения вовсе. Попробуйте что-нибудь отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43211296 . Блин, вопрос древний.

Answer (score 1):

В postgresql.conf открываете хост/порт (раскомментировать строки):

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost'
port = 5432
```

В pg_hba.conf добавляете строку:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

И перезапускаете сервис.

Comment: В pgAdmin все равно ничего не поменялось, нет соединения

Comment: При установке пароль для пользователя задавали?

Comment: указал postgres

Comment: А через psql.exe пробовали достучаться?

Comment: postgresql.conf находится по пути /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf (если запускаете в контейнере)

Answer (score 1):

Проверь состояние в "Службы"/"Services", если отключен - включи.

Answer (score 0):

listen_addresses = '*'

port = 5432

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]